# sed cannot interpret a literal hyphen

Tags: sed, escape-characters

I'm using `sed` on a command line to edit a file.

This works:

```
sed "1,/abc/d" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

It excises everything in `file1.txt` up to and including the `abc`.

But this doesn't:

```
sed "1,/abc-def/d" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Because the hyphen is supposed to be a literal, so

- I use an escape character: `sed "1,/abc\-def/d" file1.txt > file2.txt`. But it doesn't work. `sed` does not recognize it. The output file is empty.
- I try it with a wildcard character: `sed "1,/abc.def/d" file1.txt > file2.txt`.
- I use brackets: `sed "1,/abc[-]def/d" file1.txt > file2.txt`.
- I use a numerical literal: `sed "1,/abc\D2def/d" file1.txt > file2.txt`.
- And, of course, I use every conceivable combination of escape characters under the sun.

But no matter what I do, `sed` *will not* recognize a literal hyphen. How does `sed` know what I'm trying to do so that it can refuse? Is this one of those quantum mechanical things, like it will only do it if i don't check the results? Talk about confusing...

**[next day]** ok i used a hex editor to verify that it is a hyphen, ascii x2D, it is a single character. And for fun i tried again with just a naked hyphen, no luck of course. and i checked the locale, too. It said United States English.

here's another fine example. this works: **sed "1,/abc/d" file1.txt > file2.txt**

but this don't: **sed "1,/\"abc/d" file1.txt > file2.txt** not even if i use an ascii code (\x22) for the double quote, sed WON'T match it, no matter what. I still have no theory except that sed is conscious and knows what i'm trying to do.

ok thanx Kamil your example `sed "1,/abc-def/d"` did work. so did this: `sed "1,/abc\-def/d"` and this: `sed "1,/abc\x2Ddef/d"`

and I'LL BE FUKED check this out. Using my **own** *file1.txt* this works: `sed "1,/balance/d" file1.txt > file2.txt` but THIS DOESN'T: `sed "1,/\x22balance/d" file1.txt > file2.txt` Here's the actual string in file1.txt: *name="balance"* how deep does the rabbit hole go? **[\next day]**

Comment: (patched) Are you sure the file contains a hyphen and not something that _looks like_ a hyphen? Can you get the line of data you are trying to match and run it through `od -tx1` or `xxd -p` or `hexdump` or similar? Also, why do you think `\D2` has anything to do with a hyphen?

Comment: `sed "1,/abc-def/d"` does work for me. There are many hyphen/minus/dash characters in Unicode. The basic hyphen-minus (originating from ASCII) you used in `sed` most likely does not match your input.

Comment: Try [`iconv -t ASCII//TRANSLIT`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/653210/108618) to transliterate to ASCII. This should transliterate any(?) hyphen-like character to one or more hyphen-minus ASCII characters. It will possibly transliterate other characters, so use it just as a preliminary test. This: `<file1.txt iconv -t ASCII//TRANSLIT | sed "1,/abc--*def/d"` should generate non-empty output. Note I used `--*` in case your original hyphen-lookalike is long.

Comment: Assuming there is no misconception in other place(s), the fact `abc.def` does not work as expected indicates that your `sed` considers the hyphen-lookalike in your input as more than one character.  This may be related to your locale. What is the output of `locale`? Please do not respond in comments. [Edit] the question and put the information there.

Comment: Sanity check. Please run the *exact* command you're claiming doesn't work: `sed "1,/abc-def/d"`. Let it process a file containing the following lines: `1st line`, `2nd`, `3rd`, `foo abc-def-bar`, `extra line`, `whatever`. If the output is `extra line` and `whatever` then the command works and the problem has possibly nothing do do with the hyphen.

Comment: Please get familiar with the concept of [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You replaced some actual string with `abc-def`; OK, let's call it an attempt to make the example minimal. But you did not provide `file1.txt` adjusted to the example; so the example is not complete. And you did not check if the example replicates the problem. It doesn't even for *you*, so how can we replicate it? The question needs one main, firm mcve: such and such `sed` command, such and such input, such and such output, such and such desired output. Why doesn't it work? (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) Then forget about your actual file and recreate the problem from scratch by copying input and the command from text you're going to publish. If this replicates the problem for you then it will probably do this for us. What version of `sed` are you using? If you need to interpret things, do this as addendum, not instead of raw data. Instead of "here's the actual string" (your interpretation of where the culprit is) post an exact example `file1.txt` (raw data). Instead of "locale said United States English" it should be "`locale` printed `LANG=…`" (exact output).

Comment: well thanx again Kamil. I started doing like you said and came upon the answer. i discovered that the bottom half of the file had no CRs or LFs. no record separators at all. The file is about 28k, 14 lines, and the last line was was over 13k long. i didn't imagine that the target string was in the midpoint of the file but was part of the last line. And i would never have thought of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the problem turned out to be in the *file1.txt* that i was using for input. A 28k text file comprised of 14 lines of text. The 14th line was over 13k long, so when i used

```
sed "1,/abc/d" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

the target string was in the middle of the file, but it was in the very *last* record. I misread the structure of the input file. Sed was doing it's job, excluding every line up to and including the target line. The output file, *file2.txt*, was empty and i didn't know why. Thanx to everyone for your help. i should say that the real problem was incompetence. i gave the local exorcist a fat tip and sent him on his way.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that you need to escape the hyphen. The dash (or hyphen) is used to indicate a range, unless you escape it. With out the backslash, sed isn't interpreting the dash as a hyphen.

Looks to me like you are not properly escaping the hyphen. You need a back slash before the character to use as an escape character.
`sed "1,/abc\-def/d" file1.txt > file2.txt`
This will properly escape the hyphen.

The dot is a wild card for any single character and will match more than you want. Consider this command:
`echo "abc def  abc.def  abc-def   abc+def  abc++def" | sed -e "s/abc.def/+/g"`
This will look for the character string 'abcdef' and replace it with a '+' (The 'g' means global and replace everything on the line.)
`+  +  +  +  abc++def`

Now, lets change the dot to an escaped hyphen:
`echo "abc def  abc.def  abc-def   abc+def  abc++def" | sed -e "s/abc\-def/+/g"`
The answer shows exactly what you want:
`abc def  abc.def  +   abc+def  abc++def`

Note: In this example, I've put all of the entries on 1 line for clarity and added the 'g' parameter.
In your example, since you are working on lines, not words on each line, you don't need the 'g'

Comment: well what i meant to say was, i DID use a backslash to escape the hyphen, and it does not work. Sed does not recognize it, and the output, file2.txt, is empty.
so i tried everything under the sun to get what i want, and it's as if sed is conscious and knows what i'm trying to do and so refuses to comply with ANY command that will give me what i want.

Comment: No, hyphen in a regexp (just a regexp) does not mean a range, not in sed, or grep or awk or perl either. Only in a _bracket expression_ (aka character list) in a regexp it does, and there backslashing doesn't help.

Comment: THANX everyone for your answers. i'll try one at a time. It IS a hyphen i verified with a hex editor, but its ascii code is NOT \D2, (my bad) the escape code is actually \x2D, so i tried again with the right ascii escape code and, surprise, sed can't see it.
here's the actual (unsimplified) line which i'm using:
**sed "s/data\x2Dwidget\x2Dname=\"balance\"/,$d" file1.txt > file2.txt**
the actual string is **data-widget-name="balance"**
and the unequivocable document reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html#Escapes

Comment: @mikewax Sigh… The actual line should be in the question body, not in a comment deep down under an answer. The line contains invalid sed code, unless `$d` is expanded to something that makes the code valid. Are you aware the shell expands double-quoted `$d`?